# Call to operator new results in segmentation fault in MPI code

Tags: c++, mpi, new-operator

So the following line in an MPI code results in a segfault:

```
myA = new double[numMyElements*numRows];
```

, where ***numMyElements*** and ***numRows*** are both **int** -s and none of them are garbage. In my test runs ***numMyElements*numRows = 235074*** . The line of code above gets called in a constructor for an object and ***double* myA*** is a member of that class. I am using:

**g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3**
and
**mpirun (Open MPI) 1.4.3**

For now I was just running this program with only one processor i.e.

```
mpirun -np 1 ./program
```

on my laptop.

The exact error I get is the following:

```
[user:03753] *** Process received signal ***
[user:03753] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[user:03753] Signal code:  (128)
[user:03753] Failing at address: (nil)
```

After which my code hangs and I have to abort it manually. I don't think that I'm running out of heap since when looking at processes through **top** the program only uses 2.1% of memory.

However! Interestingly enough if I decrease the size i.e. I replace ***numMyElements*numRows*** with a small constant like 10 or 100 I don't get the error. I can't go higher than a 1000.

```
myA = new double[1000];
```

would result in the same error again.

Just in case my ulimit -a output:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31438
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31438
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Does anyone know what could be going on here? Thanks!

Comment: That line of code you're showing us is where things finally break down.  It more than likely is not the cause of the issue.  You may have corrupted the heap long before that line is executed. `int main() { double *d = new double [250000]; delete [] d; }` so you're saying this would also crash?

Comment: The mistake almost certainly happened some time before the line with the `new`.  Heap corruption very often has no immediate bad effects but causes a sudden death later on.

Comment: Thanks for both Quick! responses! And you're right Paul that line of code doesn't crash. I'll look into heap corruption.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it turns out it was simply an issue of incorrect array indexing unrelated to where the error popped up. Thanks for the comments!